# Collection_select contains blank values when based on SQL view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, collections

In my Rails application I have a collection_select based on a SQL view. The view works fine from SQL, and there are many entries in the view.

```
fsix_dev=> SELECT "infinitives".* FROM "infinitives";
id  |    word     | language_id | audiofile | imagefile | gender 
-----+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------
 17 | aller       |           2 |           |           |       
 61 | venir       |           2 |           |           |       
 69 | suivre      |           2 |           |           |    
 ... etc ...
```

The collection_select in my edit view:

```
.field
  = f.label :infinitive_id
  = f.collection_select :infinitive_id, Infinitive.find(:all), :id, :word, include_blank: :false, :title => "Infinitive"
```

On the page the collection_select appears to bring back an entry for each row in the view, but it is rendered with **all blank values**

```
<div class='field'>
  <label for="word_infinitive_id">Infinitive</label>
  <select id="word_infinitive_id" name="word[infinitive_id]"><option value=""></option>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=""></option>
  ... etc ...
```

**Models**

```
class Infinitive < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :word
  attr_reader :id, :word, :language_id, :audiofile, :imagefile
end

class Word < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :infinitives
  attr_accessible :word, :gender, :audiofile, :imagefile, :speech_part_id, :ssubject_id,  :present_participle, :past_participle, :tense_id, :mood_id, :infinitive_id, :question, :negative
end
```

**Controller**

```
class InfinitivesController < InheritedResources::Base
end
```

***EDIT***

As per *Valery Kvon's* note below, I have tried the following in **rails console**, and get many responses:

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > Infinitive.find(:all)
  Infinitive Load (338.9ms)  SELECT "infinitives".* FROM "infinitives" 
 => [#<Infinitive id: 17, word: "aller", language_id: 2, audiofile: nil, imagefile: nil,     gender: nil>, #<Infinitive id: 61, word: "venir", language_id: 2, audiofile: nil, imagefile:     nil, gender: nil>, ... many results ...
```

However when I try to map in :word it returns just as many results, but all nil:

```
1.9.3-p194 :002 > Infinitive.find(:all).map(&:word)
  Infinitive Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "infinitives".* FROM "infinitives" 
  => [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil ... etc ...
```

The strange thing is **word** appears as a symbol in the previous **find**.

**EDIT 2**

I tried renaming the **word** column to **infinitive_word** .... same results. Can a collection_select be built off a SQL view in Rails?

```
1.9.3-p194 :002 > Infinitive.find(:all)
  Infinitive Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "infinitives".* FROM "infinitives" 
  => [#<Infinitive id: 17, infinitive_word: "aller", audiofile: nil, imagefile: nil, gender: nil>, #<Infinitive id: 61, infinitive_word: "venir", audiofile: nil, imagefile: nil, gender: nil>, ... etc ....
```

With the map into **infinitive_word** :

```
1.9.3-p194 :003 > Infinitive.find(:all).map(&:infinitive_word)
  Infinitive Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "infinitives".* FROM "infinitives" 
  => [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil,
```

**EDIT 3**

I managed to get the **collection_select** working, but have added it as an edit rather than the answer as I do not understand why this solution was necessary. **It seems like a hacky workaround**

The solution required two changes:

- Changed the SQL view so the attribute was not the same as the relationship
- Changed **attr_reader** to **attr_accessible** on the infinitives model.

I would have expected Rails could handle having an attribute with the same name as the relationship, but more significantly I would expect an ActiveRecord relation based on a SQL view would be **attr_reader**, and not **attr_accessible**.

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove 'include_blank' OR Use `prompt` instead

```
.field
  = f.label :infinitive_id
  = f.collection_select :infinitive_id, Infinitive.find(:all), :id, :word, prompt: :false, :title => "Infinitive"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try that but it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

That because your Infinitive's :id and :word methods return nil.

```
attr_reader :id, :word
```

- that is a problem.

Moreover :word is an association and returns Word object... But for *collection_select* that method should return string/fixnum value (responsible **.to_s**).

Comment: But when I run the query against the view I receive data. I can't see where the disconnect in Rails is. Could the problem caused by using < InheritedResources::Base ?

Comment: i dont know yet. Try in console: Infinitive.find(:all).map(&:word)

Comment: I see there is a word attribute on the entity and also a word association based on the belongs_to. I will try changing one and see what happens.